# How to create relationship through other model Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have some models in my project with differents relations detailed in this picture:

[image: Diagram]

I created some models to represents each tables.

And I would to know if there is a possibility to create relationship that allows to recover all the students of teachers or all the teachers of students.

Example:

```
class Student extends Model
{
    public function clases(){
        return $this->hasMany(Clase::class, 'student_id');
    }

    /** This function doesn't works, not the great relation */
    public function teachers(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Clase::class, Teacher::class, 'student_id', 'teacher_id');
    }
}
```

I'm using Laravel 5.8

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Clase as a pivot table to define a many-to-many relation:
In your Student class (assuming 'clase' to be the table name):

```
public function teachers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class, 'clase', 'student_id', 'teacher_id');
}
```

Comment: Great idea, it's works but there are duplicates entries of Teacher, thank

Comment: You can add `->distinct()` to the end to return unique rows only.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a special relation, you need to define all foreign keys, they are perfectly described [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

I think this would work for you:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
    Teacher::class, 
    Clase::class, 
    'student_id', 
    'user_id',
    'user_id',
    'teacher_id'
);
```

Comment: Yes that's a special relation, and I tried this and it doesn't works, it return error on fields name or empty collection.